# Posts tagged with a-new-tag does not appear

Tags: posts, tags

I use wordpress 3.9.3. It already has many posts tagged with respective YEAR and are displayed under their respective tags on the relevant page.
I added new posts tagged with 2015, but they somehow refuse to appear on the post page. Is there any setting that need to be enabled for a tag?
And here is the code that should be able to handle newer years, imo.

```
<?php $year = date('Y'); ?>
<?php while ($year > 2004): ?>
<?php $pub_args = array( 'tag' => $year, 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'nopaging' => true, 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'desc' );
$pub_posts = new WP_Query($pub_args);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first line in the code is the culprit. It takes in current year and starts gathering posts from current year and goes into the past.